# pop & push subtraction and division

Tags: c, stack, switch-statement

I am reading C Programming by K&R. So, I came across pop & push. Pushing something onto stack and poping out something from stack. The calculator program made in this book adds, multiplies two popped values normally but the problem arises in the later cases i.e. subtraction and division. I read the book's explanation. However it creates a little ambiguity in my mind. What is the use of storing the popped up value into another variable, The value still remains same. Isn't it.

Also i have one doubt that is not related to the topic: In case one '0' has ASCII value of 48 and if we type '8'. These two character doesn't have the same value. So, how come the first case will be true in any of the numbers from '1' to '9' other than '0'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXOP 100   /* max size of the operand & operator */
#define NUMBER '0'  /* signal that a number was found */

int getop(char []);  
void push(double);
double pop(void);

/*reverse polish calculator*/
main()
{
int type;
double op2;
char s[MAXOP];

while((type= getop(s)) != EOF) {      
switch (type) {

case NUMBER :      <------- case 1 '0' how would this case run if other than '0' ?
push(atof(s));
break;

case '+':
push(pop() + pop());
break;

case'*': 
push(pop() * pop());
break;

case '-':
op2= pop();
push(pop() - op2);
break;

case '/': 
op2= pop();
push(pop() / op2);
break;

/* there are printf statements and default statements so not writing those */
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that operands of arithmetic are evaluated is not prescribed by the C Standard.  Therefore the assignment is to guarantee the order that pops are executed for non-commutative operators `-` and `\`.  For the commutative operators `+` and `*`, the order of pops doesn't matter, so the briefer code is certain to work.

For the question about `NUMBER`, you must study the code of `getop()`.  No doubt it returns `'0'` if *any* number is discovered on the input, no matter what that number is.

Comment: this means if 3 & 4 are taken out from stack. We have to assign one of the operand to some variable. So that we can ensure the sign will be negative or positive i.e. 3-4 =-1 or 4-3 =1 is it?

Comment: Yes.  We must ensure that when we want to compute `3 - 4` that this is actually what is computed, and not by accident `4 - 3`.

Comment: i searched a lot but can't find the getop() use...everytime i search getop() i get a getopt() result on google . @Gene can you you suggest me where i can read about getop() ?

Comment: getop is a function in the program you are studying. It is not a standard function.

Comment: oihh i seee i got it then